# Gravação de um xls binário no SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Eu tenho um arquivo xls que carrego e transformo em binário da seguinte forma:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(physicalPath + "/cadastros/documentos/" + "AWS-Estudantes_" + Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now.Year) + "-" + Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now.Month) + "-" + Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now.Day) + ".xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);                
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
_planilha = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
fs.Close();
br.Close();
```

Então chamo meu método para gravar no banco passando nome do arquivo e o `_planilha` que é `byte[] _planilha`:

```
string binary = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < _planilha.Length; i++)
{
  binary += _planilha[i];
}
```

Aqui pego os dados de dentro do `_planilha`:

```
providerFactory.ClearParameters();
providerFactory.SqlStat.Append("INSERT INTO BinaryFiles(Titulo,Arquivo) VALUES ('" + _fileName + "', CAST(CAST('" + binary + "' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS BINARY(8000))) ");
```

E aqui faço a gravação, no banco meu campo é um `binary(8000)` só que acontece que ele transforma o binário que criei do xls em um binário. Mas preciso gravar apenas o que passei para ele. Que não está acontecendo pois sem o `Cast(Cast` ele da erro de conversão.

Comment: Vc usa varbinary(8000) no banco?

Comment: Na última vez que precisei gravar o arquivo inteiro - pdf - não consegui fazer um SQL direto, tive que usar um recurso do framework q eu tenho pra adicionar um parametro; este recurso permite que eu adicione n parametros; passei o arquivo como vetor de bytes. Outra diferença é que utilizei varbinary(MAX) no banco.

Comment: Uso Binary(8000) no banco e Marco, é isso que eu fiz ali, _planilha é um byte[] que guarda os bytes de todo texto, então eu leio todos indices e concateno para binary, e então binary possui uma linha com todos bytes do arquivo e é oq ue eu gravo no banco... Mas ele não aceita gravar assim em um binary ou varbinary

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo salvar os documentos no banco de dados em Formato GZIP convertido para Base64 para evitar problema de encoding.

```
            using (var db = IMBase.getNewDBContext())
        {
            var anexo = db.AtendimentoAnexo.Create();
            anexo.TarefaAnexoId = id;
            anexo.TarefaId = tarefa;
            anexo.NomeDoArquivo = Path.GetFileName(filename);
            anexo.UsuarioId = usuario;
            anexo.Data = DateTime.Now;
            anexo.BinarioZipado = Compress.GZipCompress(filename);

            return Save<AtendimentoAnexo>(anexo, w => w.TarefaId.Equals(id));
        }
```

Método Compress.GZipCompress:

```
        public static string GZipCompress(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

        // Compress
        byte[] data = GzipCompress(file);
        if (data == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

        return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }
```

Para reaver o arquivo basta usar o Decompress.

```
        private static byte[] base64_decode(string encodedData)
    {
        byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
        return encodedDataAsBytes;
    }       

    private static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
    {
        using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var buffer = new byte[4096];
            int read;

            while ((read = zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            return resultStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```